# How would I detect a physical attack in video form?

Tags: algorithms, python, machine-learning

I hope this question isn't too vague because it's more a discussion than a question. I want to write a code which can detect physical violence in a scene (with the end result being the prediction of triggers in the movie/show). I would like to do this through python (however I'm open to ideas of other codes- I'm familiar with MATLAB, python, html, javascipt, C and C++) however I'm not quite sure what to search for in the scene which can accurately be identified as "physcial abuse"?

So far I've thought about:

- Detecting blood colour on skin colour on a screen
- Detecting a very fast moving skin colour across a screen
- Detecting the audio which comes with physical attacks

Obviously each of these have different pros and cons but I'm mainly looking for an algorithm that misdetects as little as possible. Please let me know what you all think!!

Comment: That is a very fuzzy and very difficult problem, and can't really be addressed by an algorithm. The state of the art is to create a corpus of video scenes that both contain violence and don't, pay multiple people to label these scenes appropriately, and then train a suitable neural network on this corpus. With enough iterations, it might converge onto a suitable predictor for violence.

Comment: What amon says. Forget Python, you will need a development tool with AI support. And then I am not even sure whether, with the current state of the technology,  this could yield useful results at all. It would probably be more effective to have one or more humans review the video and I believe this is what the big guys still do.

Comment: If you go with an AI solution the biggest problem you face is getting a large data set of videos that have been classified to contain (or not contain) a wide enough variety of violence. This may be a problem AI can solve. But not without a training set.

Answer (score 2):

For starters.

What is defined as Physical Abuse?

Put it to you another way. *If someone is slapped on the back, is that physical abuse?*

- Even though in the previous scene they were choking
- Even though in the previous scene they scored a difficult goal
- Even though in the previous scene they messed something up and are feeling terribly guilty
- Even though in the previous scene a fly landed on their back.

You have two problems here.

- A Definitional problem.
- Computer Vision.

The computer vision problem isn't solved, the best we have are Neural Nets that have been trained using large sets of data. This is probably the only way to solve the problem, as its how the natural world solved the problem. Unfortunately nature has some 500+ million years head start.

The definitional problem, is a SCARY problem. (SCARY is an acronym). In short the only way to solve it is to reach some consensus in the moment. The next moment it will have shifted. 20 years ago Robocop the movie was rated MA, its now rated R. The content of the movie hasn't changed, just how we perceive the content.

Comment: Can you add an expansion of the acronym SCARY? I failed to find it with a quick google search.

Comment: Weird, I can't find the definition either. Could be that I've misremembered it. Anyway what I meant is that there are problems in real life that have no solution. There is no categorical way to solve it. You can't even draw circles around definitely is and defiantly is not. If there is a solution to be made, it is only made by negotiating, and by definition that means having failed in some way. eg: no matter what agreement is reached in Palestine/Israel everyone is going to be unhappy. No matter what action you define as violence, some of those actions will not be violent in nature.